# Difficulties setting up JOGL on IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, graphics, jogl

I'm trying to set up JOGL on IntelliJ Idea for a school project but somehow I always mess it up. I downloaded the .7z folder jogl-all jar and the other ones everything. I followed the intellij idea setup tutorial on official jogl page but thst didn't work too. I tried reinstalling, changing Java version, trying it with maven, looking up different tutorials trying newer and older versions of jogl. Nothing worked I still don't why, and also why it has to be this complicated.

That's why as a final point I turn to stack overflow to ask here. Can someone please help me.

Also I'm not the most advanced in java, still a student.

I downloaded the .7z folder jogl-all jar and the other ones everything. I followed the intellij idea setup tutorial on official jogl page but thst didn't work too. I tried reinstalling, changing Java version, trying it with maven, looking up different tutorials trying newer and older versions of jogl.

Comment: You just have to put the JogAmp fat JAR jogamp-fat.jar into the classpath of your project, it's in the project settings. Contact us rather on the official JogAmp forum. Please be more accurate. Indicate precisely what doesn't work, the error message, the full stack trace, a reproducer, your operating system, etc.

Comment: https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php?title=Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE#Add_a_library_dependency_to_your_project